# ActionBarSherlock ShareActionProvider for Android 2.3 not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I'm using ABS the ShareActionProvider.
I have followed this code : https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ShareActionProviders.java and its working with the latest version of Android (4.0+) but not with Android 2.x, I can't click on the icon.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share, menu);

    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
    actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
    actionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
    actionProvider.setShareIntent(share("More apps : https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Stéphane+Mathis"));

    if(mItem != null)
    {
        actionProvider.setShareIntent(share(mItem.content));        
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

private Intent share(String message) 
{
    final Intent MessIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    MessIntent.setType("text/plain");
    MessIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    return MessIntent;
}
```

Did I miss something ?

EDIT : 
I tried the "official" demo from ABS and it's not working in the emulator, but it works on a real device. It's the same thing with my code, working with a real device ( tested with 4.1.2, 4.2.1 and 2.3.3) but not in the emulator. So what do I do ? I feel unconfortable to publish an app that doesn't work when I test it in the emulator.

Comment: No error. But I'he just seen this line in warning : `Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsListPopupWindow.<init>`. Is it related to my problem ?

Comment: Got exactly same problem, were you able to resolve it? Also are you using android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider" in your CAB menu xml?

Comment: No, I have published my app with this problem.
And yes, i'm using `actionProviderClass` with that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is due to a bug described [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/415), in short emulator does not have more than 1 app installed that is able to get this share intent.